# Inconsistent dimensions: kernel and range of $f: \mathbb{R}[x]_2 \rightarrow C[0, 1]$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $f: \mathbb{R}[x]_2 \rightarrow C[0, 1]$ be a linear transformation defined as

$$f(ax^2+bx+c) = (b-a)e^x +(c-a)e^{2x} +(b-c)e^{3x}$$

Here, $\mathbb{R}[x]_2$ is the vector space of all polynomials of degree $n \leq 2$ and $C[0, 1]$ the space of all continuous functions in the range $[0, 1]$.

I will compute the kernel and the range of $f$ in what seems to me an appropriate fashion, and arrive at an impossible result. I would highly appreciate if someone could point out where my error is.

---

**I :** Let $u = e^x$. Then $f(ax^2+bx+c) = (b-c)u^3 + (c-a)u^2 + (b-a)u$. Observe that

\begin{align*}
    &(b-c)u^3 + (c-a)u^2 + (b-a)u &= 0 \\
    \iff &u\Big[(b-c)u^2 + (c-a)u + (b-a) \Big] &= 0
\end{align*}

The trivial solution is $u = 0$. However, not only $u \neq 0$ for any $x$, but we are interested in the subspace of the *domain* that makes the linear transformation null. Hence, we may only inspect

\begin{align*}
    (b-c)u^2 + (c-a)u + (b -a) = 0
\end{align*}

This will hold if and only if

\begin{align*}
    \begin{cases}
        b -a &= 0 \\
        c -a &= 0 \\
        b- c &= 0
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

which has as infinite solution space all cases where $a = b =c$. Then

\begin{align*}
    kern(f) &= \Big\{~ (ax^2 + bx + c) \in \mathbb{R}[x]_2 \mid a = b = c  ~\Big\} \\
    &= \Big\{a(x^2 + x + 1) \mid a \in \mathbb{R} \Big\}
\end{align*}

Hence the kernel of $f$ is a one-dimensional space spanned by the polynomial vector $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]_2$ whose coefficients are all $1$.

**II :** Now consider the fact that any $g \in \text{Im}(f)$ is of the form $(b-c)u^3 + (c-a)u^2 + (b-a)u$. This means this linear combination spans the whole range of $f$. Furthermore,

\begin{align*}
    &e^{3x}(b-c) + e^{2x}(c-a) + e^x(b-a) &= 0 \\
    &a_1e^{3x} + a_2e^{2x} + a_3e^x &= 0
\end{align*}

has $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$, so $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 0$ is the only solution and the set is linearly independent. Hence, $\text{Im}(f)$ is a three-dimensional space.

**III :** The domain of $f$, $\mathbb{R}[x]_2$, is spanned by the linearly independent set $\{1, x, x^2 \}$ and is therefore a three-dimensional space. Our results imply the domain of $f$ is four-dimensional, since its null space is one-dimensional and its range is three-dimensional. I have failed to spot my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\text{span}\{e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x}\} \neq \text{Image}(f)$. For example $e^x$ is in the span but it is not in the image of $f$. The reason being, in the image of $f$, the difference of the coefficients of $e^x$ and $e^{2x}$ should be the coefficient of $e^{3x}$. In the example I have given, such is not the case.

Observe that
\begin{align*}
f(1)&=e^{2x}-e^{3x}\\
f(x)&=e^x+e^{3x}\\
f(x^2)&=-e^x-e^{2x}.
\end{align*}
This shows that
$$f(1)+f(x)+f(x^2)=0.$$

[note: *you can also get this fact from your computations for the kernel*]

Thus the image of the basis $\mathcal{B}=\{1,x,x^2\}$ is not a linearly independent set , so the dimension of the range can be no more than $2$. The fact that $\{f(1), f(x)\}$ is a linearly independent set shows that the dimension is exactly $2$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am sure I'm simply being limited, but how can $f(1) + f(x) + f(x^2) = 0$ show $S := \{e^x, e^{2x}, e^{3x} \}$ is linearly dependent? If we arrange the sum, we obtain $-e^{3x} + e^{3x} - e^{2x} + e^{2x} -e^x + e^x = 0$ which is equivalent to $0e^{3x} + 0e^{2x} + 0e^x = 0$, which clearly doesn't prove the linear dependence of $S$.

Comment: I'm very new to linear algebra, so sorry for not grasping what you are intending to show.

Comment: After playing around for a while in paper I've arrived to your exact same conclusions (although I had to take a slightly lengthier path to see why your reasoning made sense). Thank you so much for your answer!